# How to send ethers to a contract during its deployment in hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

Let's say I have this contract.

```
contract Wallet{
   string value;
   function balance() public view returns(uint){
      return  address(this).balance;
   }
   constructor(string memory _value) payable{
      value =_value;
   }
}
```

I am using hardhat as the development environment. I want to send ethers to this contract
while I deploy this. Is there any way? (Like, this doesn't work)

```
  const wallet = await Wallet.deploy{from :account1.address,value:1}("Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ethers.js, you can use [override](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall)

```
const wallet = await Wallet.deploy("Hello",
    {
        from :account1,
        value:1
    });
```

from: should be type of `signer`, and `value: 1` is sending `1 wei`, not `1 ether`.

If you want to convert this number into eth, you can use this:

`ethers.utils.parseEther('1')` that will returns 1 ether with 18 decimals format